# Comparar dos fechas con formato YYYY-mm-dd en javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

estoy en apuros con un temita de comparación de fechas, necesito comparar dos fechas con formato "2018-10-05" para poder llamar una funcion o hacer calculos, estuve leyendo y la verdad me estoy complicando la vida, alguien podría darme una ayuda? Los leo muchas gracias

```
function CompararFechas(fechaVencimiento,fechaPago){
    var fechaVencimiento   = fechaVencimiento;
    var fechaPago          = fechaPago;

    if (){
    } else if (){   
    }
}
```

Comment: Si tu pregunta fue respondida correctamente favor de marcar la respuesta como correcta para que sea marcada como resuelta.

Comment: gracias por el comentario, ya marque la respuesta como correcta, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment" />
<script>
moment.now() > moment(2016-11-23); //Regresa un boolean
</script>
```

Te recomiendo que uses moment. le pasas como parametro la fecha que deseas comparar. Te paso la liga de la documentacion:
https://flaviocopes.com/momentjs/

Comment: Gracias por contestar Leo voy a mirar la documentación que me facilitas!

Comment: te hago una consulta rápida, se puede comparar la fecha que tengo guardada en un variable? sería algo así? moment(fechaVencimiento)

Comment: Si. sin problemas.

Comment: Puedes hacer restas de fechas tambien.